# changing to a different view with animation on rotation

Tags: ios, animation, uiviewcontroller, delegates, autorotate

This ought to be simple, but oddly I haven't found a good answer for it.

Let's say I'm trying to make an app that is just like apple's calculator, which upon rotation, doesn't just move buttons around, but switches to an entirely new view... what are the simplest possible mechanics of that?

I'd really like to work from here:

[Calculator Storyboards http://content.screencast.com/users/iamafractal/folders/Jing/media/0a8469d1-5d3e-4d4b-ba71-9a0ed085650f/00001158.png](http://content.screencast.com/users/iamafractal/folders/Jing/media/0a8469d1-5d3e-4d4b-ba71-9a0ed085650f/00001158.png)

I vaguely understand that I need a rotation related method in a view controller, and some kind of delegate, and maybe another view controller for the other view, but I'd like it if the two view controllers shared as much code as possible... so is there a view controller class and then the other vc is a daughter of that just with the extra methods to cover the additional buttons and functionality? so how would that look in code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can keep the same `viewController` and can keep different `UIView` for both orientations.

on checking the `interfaceOrientation` in `shouldAutoRotateToInterfaceOrientation` and on receiving any of the landscape orientations, show landscape view and in else case show Portrait View.

Comment: Look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8570221/use-accelerometer-in-my-movieplayer-app/8646856#8646856 to see some code.

Comment: @DaveKliman, in your case, you would need to check interfaceOrientation not deviceOrientation

Answer (score 0):

You can present the landscape view controller modally when the device orientation is changed to landscape, and dismiss it when it reverts to portrait.

EDIT: it's best to use `UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve` as the `modalTransitionStyle` of the modal view controller.